Ibn kammuna argument against divine simplicity?
Because of my bad English I will present the argument from the article Suhrawardī and Ibn Kammūna on the Impossibility of Having Two Necessary Existents

If there were two necessary [existents] in Being, then (a) there would not be commonality between them in all aspects, for there must be something which distinguishes (mumayyiz) between them; (b) nor would there be difference between them in all aspects, for they must share necessity of existence. Thus, there must be both commonality and distinction between them, and this entails the possibility of that which is divided (al-muqassam) and that which divides (al-muqassim), while we have assumed two necessary existents: but this is impossible. [Furthermore,] the Necessary Existent has no partition in some other way such that it comes to be caused according to its partition and thereby made possible.



If the necessity of existence (wujüb al-wujud) of each necessary existent (X and Y, as in our previous examples) is either a mental suppositional or superadded to the essence of them, then:

One may assume that the two necessary existents are sharing this necessity of existence.

Moreover, this necessity of existence would not be the same as the essence of either necessary existent; rather it would be accidental
to each.

Each necessary existent would have a complete and independent essence (tamam al-mahiyya), despite sharing this necessity of
existence.

It follows from 1-4 that each necessary existent would be a necessary existent in itself (or in virtue of its essence).

Thus, it is possible to have two necessary existents.



Some Islamic philosophers have argued that this will lead to contradiction because if the two necessary existents are simple, and there is commonality and distinction between them , then this means the two simple necessary existents will be composed from that which is common and distinct between them. But what if The two simple necessary existents: there is no commonality or distinction between them. There is only a distinction between them. Ibn Kammuna proposes the multiplicity of the necessary existent while maintaining its identity as simple and non-composite. The concept (necessity) applies either from itself or not from itself. Ibn Kammuna claims that it is not from itself in the case of the necessity of existence.
The necessity of necessity is incidental and contingently applies.
The concept of the necessary existent is the referent of the necessary existent in the mind.
And the referent of the necessary existent is the concept, but in external reality.
The referent must have a particularity in order for the concept to be abstracted correctly. This particularity exists in the other necessary existent.
What's your opinion on ibn kammuna argument?

"there is no [...] distinction between them".... "There is only a distinction between them." -- this sentence contradicts itself. What did you intend here?

So I meant that there is no commonality or distinction between them, because that will make them composed of that which is common and distinct between the two simple gods, which leads to contradiction (because ibn kammuna already said that both of them are simple) Which differs from when we say that "there are only a distinction between them" that does not open the possibility of the two necessary existents being composed from commonality and distinction. This is what I meant

Ah, ok! makes sense now.

Divine simplicity means that God's essence is His existence and all His properties are identical to His essence. This is a very weird idea and Plantinga has attacked to this idea (and in some sense meaningless). Why a necessary existent can not have a partition? What view Ibn Kammuna assumes about properties? Nominalism? a kind Realism? Tropism?. Without these clarifications we can not judge the argument.

@Arian and when gods essence is his existence, then he is not composed of anything, which then is described as divine simplicity and that is when a being is not composed of anything, his existence is his essence, his attributes are his essence...etc. and on why God can not have a partition, well the post directly speaks about the belief of the necessary existence being simple, but also if the necessary existence is composed of partition then he is no longer a necessary being, he rely on his parts.

he needs "those parts" because he's composed from those parts...so basically he is not necessary by himself...and that is not the "point" this post Stands for...

"if the necessary existence is composed of partition then he is no longer a necessary being, he rely on his parts" why? Suppose that his parts are all necessary.  The definition of a necessary existent is as follows : a being which exists in all possible worlds. This definition does not rule out a necessary composite object.

Well I do not follow with this definition its just not in depth, a necessary existence" an entity which subsists through itself and requires no external cause in order to exist", so...a necessary existence that require no external cause, is composed from necessary parts which then he requires an external cause(which are the necessary parts that the necessary existence is composed of) so the necessary existent is not a necessary existence by definition

Also, if I will follow your definition, a necessary existence is a being which exists in all possible worlds. Then existence is necessary for this being, so he cannot be non existence nor he can have the possibility to be non-existent...but he is a composite necessary existence, if he is stripped from what he is composed of then he would have the possibility to be non-existent...so not a necessary being...because composition is what shapes this necessary existence...again not the point of the post.

Needs, Cause, external cause,...are not a part of the definition of necessary objects. "if he is stripped from what he is composed of..." as I said if the component are all necessary He can not be stripped of from what He are composed of. When we say that God is omniscient or God is omnipotent, simplicity of God depends on what view  we have about "metaphysics of properties". In nominalism God is simple and there is no identity between his essence and attitudes (as there is no property at all), in tropism the situation is different, so the ibn Kammuna's argument highly affected in each case.

Re your "this necessity of existence would not be the same as the essence of either necessary existent" which seems problematic, why the said necessity of existence would not be the same? Seems the said necessity of existence is contextualized but in itself is still same. Otherwise the necessary contextualization itself is a more necessary existence unit. Also if anyone can imagine the two different necessary simples, then there must be something else in common otherwise 'two' here is an immediate contradiction...

My mathematical brain finds this style of philosophical writing very very hard to follow. Head was spinning after the first read.
I went ahead and tried to parse it into formal logic so I can better get at what is trying to be said here.

Let's define some terms: 
E(x) := The set of descriptors of the essence of x 
N(x) := "x has the property of necessity of existence", 
C(x,y,z) := "z ∈ E(x) ∩ E(y)" 

If there were two necessary [existents] in Being, then (a) there would not be commonality between them in all aspects, for there must be something which distinguishes (mumayyiz) between them; (b) nor would there be difference between them in all aspects, for they must share necessity of existence. Thus, there must be both commonality and distinction between them[...]

Fundamental assumption

∃xy N(x) ∧ N(y) ∧ x≠y

Non-identity of existents implies non-commonality

x≠y → ∃z ¬C(x,y,z)

Necessary existents have necessary existence in common

N(x) ∧ N(y) →C(x,y,"necessary existence")

So far, so good. We have properties, one of which is necessary existence. We've assumed two existents that have the property of necessary existence.
Therefore, the two existents share 'necessary existence' as a property but must differ in other ways so as to be distinct.

[...] and this entails the possibility of that which is divided (al-muqassam) and that which divides (al-muqassim), while we have assumed two necessary existents: but this is impossible. [Furthermore,] the Necessary Existent has no partition in some other way such that it comes to be caused according to its partition and thereby made possible.

So here we are saying that since both the intersection and symmetric difference of properties of the two existents are non-empty, we can remove the common properties to partition the remaining properties of each necessary existent. But since "necessary existence" is one of the shared properties, neither of the resulting partitions can contain that property.

D = E(x) ∩ E(y) 
E'(x) = E(x)\D and E'(y) = E(y)\D 
∴ 
"necessary existence" ∉ E'(x) and "necessary existence" ∉ E'(y)

We now have three partitions of essences, E'(x), E'(y), and D. However, only D has the property of necessary existence, whereas E'(x), and E'(y) would need to be combined with D to become necessary.
Therefore, we have only one necessary existent, the one with properties D, and the original two are both metaphysically dependent on D for their necessity. This contradicts the assumption that we have two independent necessary existents.

The above seems to have an implicit modal assumption on the nature of the necessity of necessary existence:

∀w ◻N(w) → ◻¬∃u[u≠w ∧ ◻N(u)]

Therefore, if we want to maintain that there are two necessary existents, then we have to, at a minimum, deny the antecedent of the above conditional:

∀w ¬◻N(w) ⇔ ∀w ◇N(w)

With the first conditional neutralized, we can now assert:

∀w [N(w) ⇔ ◇∃q E(q) = E(w)/"necessary existence"]

The above reflects the author's subsequent reasoning about the contingency of necessary existence:

If the necessity of existence (wujüb al-wujud) of each necessary existent (X and Y, as in our previous examples) is either a mental suppositional or superadded to the essence of them, then [...] [o]ne may assume that the two necessary existents are sharing this necessity of existence. Moreover, this necessity of existence would not be the same as the essence of either necessary existent; rather it would be accidental to each.


Conclusion
I see what the author is saying, but it requires assuming that no essence necessarily has necessary existence (i.e., necessity of existence is a contingent aspect of somethings essence).

Amazing answer!
